# How to make all outgoing RST drop

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, linux-kernel, iptables

I am trying to drop all the outgoing RST and incoming RST on all ports. I am using Debian linux. I tried all possible combinations of commands listed on the internet but nothing seems to work.

For example, i tried:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -j DROP  
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j DROP  
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -j DROP
```

Still i am seeing RST packets being sent by the kernel and also receiving RST packets. Please try to resolve this issue

Comment: The state tracking `-m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED` seems unrelated (no pun intended) but the rest looks good. Perhaps there are other rules in the `INPUT`/`OUTPUT` chains that come before the ones you've added and are allowing the packets? The big question though is why in the world you would ever want to do something like this.

Comment: I am working on an class project and i cannot move forward until this issue is resolved

Comment: Anyway, the linux is installed in virtualbox. I am not doing this on my host OS

Comment: How are you verifying the rules aren't working? If you are running wireshark on the same machine as the iptables rules and are seeing the RSTs, that is expected. Wireshark will see ALL packets, even those dropped by iptables.

Comment: i am running wireshark on both my machine and remote machine. There is evidence that RST is sent by my machine and reached remote machine

Comment: Please elaborate...  Are these rules being done on the VM or the host OS?  Are you seeing the RST packets on the VM or the host OS?  Filtering within the VM will not prevent RST packets being sent by the host machine.

Comment: These rules are done on the VM. I am seeing RST packets on the VM. Actually, the command like this worked 2 months ago...but i forgot to note down the command. now the suffering...

Comment: I don't see how you can rationally suppress *outgoing* RSTs without breaking TCP/IP completely.

Comment: @EJP I am trying to do a man in the middle attack for a class project. I am acting as a fake router and when a client sends me any message, i manipulate its parameters like IP, MAC, etc and forward it to router and vice-versa. I dont need to break the ongoing connection. The only problem i am facing is, as my machine an attacker and i am forging the packet by changing the IP/MAC address of the packet, the kernel is not accepting the forged IP-MAC combination and sending RST towards the router. So, unless i suppress this RST, i cannot forward the messages to both the client and the router

Comment: Solved the problem...if i specify source and destination addresses the rule is being applied. If i do for all packets, iptables is not accepting that rule.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmm, it's quite possible that this is going through the forward chain rather than the input or output chain, since you are running this on the host machine.

A trick to debug this is to use *iptables -L -v*, this displays counts of how many packets go to each rule, if you set up a command that send lots of packets like this

```
watch --interval 0.1 "nc remote.machine CLOSED_PORT"
```

you can work out which rule is getting hit. You should also be aware that there are orthogonal tables - sets of rule chains used in different situations (e.g for nat). It might be worth looking in the NAT table - since your virtual host might be NAT'ing through your host rather than having it's own IP address

```
iptables -L -v -t nat
```

It would be informative to know what IP address the virtual host has - since if this is disjoint from your network's subnet this will probably be being NAT'ed.

Answer (score 12):

If you are looking to drop inbound RST packets, you will want to do this:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL RST,ACK -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL RST -j DROP
```

If you are looking to drop *outbound* RST packets, you will want to do this:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL RST,ACK -j DROP
```

**Why RST ACK?**
According to the RFC, any response to a TCP packet including a SYN must ACK that sequence number. Therefore, even if you are indicating that your port is closed, you respond with a RST ACK.

**Why care about outbound RST?**
If you're trying to use a tool like Scapy to experiment with IP behavior, you will frequently need to prevent the host's IP stack from sending back a RST ACK. Alternatively, you could implement a pseudo-stack in Scapy, claiming a MAC, responding to ARP or ICMP ND for IPv6, and bind your own IP address, which will also prevent the host's stack from responding. Clearly, this is more work than simply blocking outbound RST packets.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I have to use a bit different command line to drop outbound RST packets (i.e., no ACK flag): "iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL RST -j DROP"

Comment: Well, that seems appropriate since I clearly stated in this answer that it drops only RST-ACK packets.

Answer (score 0):

Reset packets have RST and ACK flags activated.
So, the correct rule is:

`iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL RST,ACK -j DROP`

Comment: Do they indeed? ACK of what? A segment that is intended for a connection that doesn't exist? Why would you ACK that?

Comment: Ok, sorry. I was working in a particular problem where packets where ack+rst, but sure not all rst packets have ack flag.
But maybe the problem of Justin is packets with rst+ack are not filtered by rst only filter

Comment: You were quite right, @adrianlzt. If someone sends you a SYN, the proper response *must* include an ACK of the sequence number + 1. Therefore, even a closed port will respond to a SYN with a RST/ACK. It's in the RFC.

Answer (score -3):

Hope it helps:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rst_retries
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rst_timeout
```